# Should I CC the general manager in my job application?

Tags: resume, human-resources

I was about to email the General Manager my resume to inquire for a career opportunity, but suddenly I came across a job posting for a specific position. My instinct tells me to send it to the HR manager and CC it to the General Manager but I feel conflicted. My reasoning is that a company of that size (60+ employees) has proper procedures acquiring human resource talent, but I can't help feeling that maybe the General Manager has better understanding with the operations and is therefore able find the best suited position for different talents.

Would including the General Manager in the email reflect negatively on my application or will it make no difference?

Answer (score 2):

The general manager will invariably delete your email.  Managers typically get a large amount of unsolicited emails, so you shouldn't expect a direct email to be read or acted upon.

Stay with the HR route.

Answer (score -1):

Skip the HR, and send the hiring manager a well crafted resume and personalized cover letter describing how you're a good fit for the job. Send it via snail mail, as opposed to e-mail, to make it more likely for the manager to read it.

Comment: To the downvoter, this is basically the advice regularly given by Liz Ryan, who writes an advice column for Forbes, aimed at job seekers and employees